# Run Nodejs program that ignores parent node_modules

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a library and I want to test it by doing a full install locally before publishing to npm. One of the things I want to test is if all the dependencies are part of the project. Because of how nodejs structures its module system though, ([a nodejs module is searched for at every directory level](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/all.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)) I do not have a good way to ensure that the module I am requiring came from the current folder's node_modules, and not the parent folder's node_modules.

Here is the project structure:

```
library-folder/
  package.json
  node_modules/
  testing/integration/
    package.json
    node_modules/
    test-install.js
```

I want to know if there is a way to tell nodejs to only require modules from the current directory, and ignore any parent directories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with babel-jest dependency when running npm start in a React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089122/issue-with-babel-jest-dependency-when-running-npm-start-in-a-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

> I do not have a good way to ensure that the module I am requiring came from the current folder's node_modules, and not the parent folder's node_modules.

For that, you can use [`require.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) and check the path it returns.

Comment: I don&#39;t believe this will work based on their documentation:
"Each of these paths is used as a starting point for the module resolution algorithm, meaning that the node_modules hierarchy is checked from this location." 
I cannot check this atm but I will check it later today

Comment: @andykais Looks like you've read the description of `options.paths` field. The method description is written after the bullet points: `Use the internal require() machinery to look up the location of a module, but rather than loading the module, just return the resolved filename.`

Comment: Thank you, you are right that this will get me partway there, but I think the issue I am trying to solve is not possible. Say I want to be sure my real deps are not devDeps. Even if I know that `testing/integration/test-install.js` is using the `integration/node_modules` folder, any dependencies of my library will still look in both `integration/node_modules` and `library-folder/node_modules` because each require location is just a starting point. I think my real solution is to just test in a sibling folder.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issues by creating a file in the child's root project folder.

File's name should be called like this:  `.env`

The content: `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`